# ArrayBound Exception Error

Tags: java

When I execute the following program it displays an array bound exception:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Array {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
    BufferedReader ch=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Hello World\n");

    System.out.println ("\nEnter the number of elements:");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(ch.readLine());

    int a[]=new int[n];

    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(ch.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println ("\nThe elements are as follows:\n");

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println (a[i]+"\t");
    }


  }
}
```

output:
Hello World

Enter the number of elements:
1
2

The elements are as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Array.main(Array.java:26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the array by giving the array size say 5, then array is created with indices 0 to 4. But you are looping from indices 1 to 5. 
Since you are trying to access array index 5, you are getting the error. 
Use `for (int i=0;i<n;i++)`